# Testing IFA in iOS 10 Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8, ios10

Using the Xcode 8 beta I try to get the IFA and checking this with the simulator - however, it´s always 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

Is that expected? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check in Setting->Privacy->Advertising->Limit Ad Tracking.
Having that on is apparently going to result in a zero'd out IFA in iOS 10. If it's not that it may just be Simulator flakiness. Mine is consistently showing the IFA but the IFV is zero'd out.